# Android application generates .old extension on file

Tags: android, sqlite, mobile, thread-safety

I have an Android application that communicates with a server developed on Java EE.

The mobile application manipulates threads and a synchronization task that's read and written in a sqlite database.

The problem is that in several occasions the database is corrupt, and the extension file is changed to .old. This represents a difficult problem because the application is crashed and the data is lost.

Can you recommended an idea of how procced in this case?